# If variable = number, do X, else do nothing

Tags: jquery, if-statement, expand, var

I wrote a jquery code that is going to expand certain elements on hover. I want the code to only expand if not expanded. Here is my code. It doesn't seem to be working correctly.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var labelstatus = 0;
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.rm").hover(function () {
        if (labelstatus != 1){
            $("#expensereduction,#envimpact,#mtextlft,#initaud,#energaud").fadeOut();
            var currentFontSize = $('.initiate').css('font-size');
            var currentFontSizeNum = parseFloat(currentFontSize, 10);
            var newFontSize = currentFontSizeNum*3;
            $('.initiate').delay(500).animate({
                fontSize: newFontSize
            });
            return false;
            var labelstatus = 1;
        }
        else {
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What does "not working correctly" mean?  What is it doing that is not correct?

Comment: Why the two $(document).ready(function() ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are declaring local variables inside the functions, so they are independent of each other. Also, you get a new variable each time, so the previous value doesn't persist.

Also, you are calling `return` before assigning the variable, which will exit out of the function, so the assignment will never happen.

You need to declare the variable in a scope outside the functions:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var labelstatus = 0;

  $("a.rm").hover(function () {
    if (labelstatus != 1){
      $("#expensereduction,#envimpact,#mtextlft,#initaud,#energaud").fadeOut();
        var currentFontSize = $('.initiate').css('font-size');
        var currentFontSizeNum = parseFloat(currentFontSize);
        var newFontSize = currentFontSizeNum * 3;
        $('.initiate').delay(500).animate({
            fontSize: newFontSize
        });
        labelstatus = 1;
        return false;
    }
    else {
    }
  });

});
```

Also: the `parseFloat` function doesn't have a radix parameter.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the explanation. Wasn't aware that var defined only local variables. Thanks!

Comment: @dylfreak6494: The `var` keyword is used to declare all variables. If it's used inside a function it will declare a local variable, and if it's used in the global scope it will create a global variable. If you use a variable without declaring it, it will implicitly be declared in the global scope.

Answer (score 7):

this...

```
    return false;
    var labelstatus = 1;
```

should be...

```
    labelstatus = 1;
    return false;
```

---

...and this...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var labelstatus = 0;
});
```

should be...

```
var labelstatus = 0;
```

---

- Code that comes after the `return` statement will not run
- Using `var` makes `labelstatus` local to the function
- You really don't need two `$(document).ready(function() {` calls. Put your code in one, and you can make `labelstatus` local to that handler so that all code inside can use it.

Answer (score 0):

`labelstatus` won't be set to `1` as the function is already returned in the line before.